# Overwriting a string in a FileStream

Tags: c#

The code I have is:

```
string sMD5Hash = sb.ToString();

using(Stream stream = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    stream.Seek(5, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sMD5Hash), 0, sMD5Hash.Length);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, seek to 5 and start writing my string there. Not regular writing because it will push the next bytes forward. But instead, I want to overwrite the bytes. How could I do it?

Comment: Use Position when setting an absolute position and Seek when setting a relative position. stream.Position = 5;

Comment: 'Regular writing' is overwriting. Shifting data (to insert something) is quite hard.

Comment: Code should be doing what you want... Could you please clarify why do you believe it will "push the next bytes forward"?

Comment: Oh.. thank you and sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make FileStream `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` and `FileAccess.ReadWrite`

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    stream.Seek(5, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sMD5Hash), 0, sMD5Hash.Length);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work, `Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` is the syntax and there's no 4th parameter/overload

Comment: Now I get this: `Additional information: Unable seek backward to overwrite data that previously existed in a file opened in Append mode.` at the Seek part

Comment: Current version of the post provides code *identical* to code in the question (as `FileAccess.ReadWrite` is default) - please clarify why do you believe it is different... And what exactly is the problem you are solving (as code in the question seem to be doing exactly what question seem to be asking about).